# Creating rpm/deb packages for different configurations of my app which will replace each other

Tags: rpm, packaging, deb

TL;DR I want to ship my application in two configurations: basic package and full package with additional modules. How do i do that?

I have two packages for my application for CentOS: `app.rpm` which is a lightweight configuration and `app_full.rpm` which is a full configuration with additional modules. I'd like to make them replace each other on installation if the version of the new package is equal or newer then the version of installed package.
I've tried to use `Obsoletes:`  as it's shown [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/#renaming-or-replacing-existing-packages). The problem is that my app resides in `/opt/app/` in both packages. So what happens is that Yum installs the new package overwriting old files in `/opt/app/` (which is ok) and then removes the old package (and `/opt/app/`).

I actually use a script to install this app which does a bunch of things before the installation (adds repo or downloads .rpm/.deb if needed depending on system). So, the solution I see here is to make this script to check if another package is installed, to check versions of both installed and new packages and then to run `yum uninstall` and `yum install`. But it seems like dirty workaround.

The other thing I can think of is to create `app_additions.rpm` which contains additional modules and to make `app_full.rpm` which contains both `app.rpm` and `app_additions.rpm`. I haven't tried it yet. Will this work? If I install `app_full` and then uninstall `app` what will happen with `app_additions` and `app_full` packages? Is there a way to make these packages uninstall with 'app'?

So what is the right way to do this?
I'd also like to know the same about .deb packages.

Comment: I think obsoletes: is simply the wrong tag.

Comment: And yes, your second approach is useful. To answer your question "how to make dependent packages uninstall on removal of the dependency": that's exactly what dependencies inherently are for.